# AfterEffects Text Templates - Do changes Progagate to Instances in PPro

Tags: after-effects, premiere, export

I have created a number of Live Text Template Capsule (.aecap) files from AE CC2017. And used them a number of places in multiple timelines in a Premiere project. I now need to make a tweak to background layers. If I make the change in AE do I need to re-export the aecap file and if so, do I overwrite the old cap file? I don't want to loose all the instances in my PPro timeline and the unique text associated with each.

What's the proper way to update the AE portion of Text Templates after they are used in Premiere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating in AE does not update the template in PPro directly -like updating a direct linked AE project-composition does.

To update Live Text Templates that are already used in Premiere: Update the composition in AE and export Composition as Text Template (.aecap) and Overwrite the previous .aecap file. It will update in Premiere after a RESTART without loosing the unique text in the instances you've already used. Note: just making the element offline and then relinking does not seem to update it. It's possible if I deleted the preview files it would work, but I haven't tried it. So far a Restart of PPro is required to update the Live Text Template.